# call servlet from html form without web.xml deployment descriptor

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

How can I call a servlet from the form's action without using the web.xml deployment descriptor?

Comment: You can't. The `web.xml` is how servlets work.

Comment: What would be the point?

Comment: @matt: to distribute as JAR, for example. Just include in classpath and it'll be registered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade to Java EE 6 / Servlet 3.0, then you'll be able to register the servlet by the [`@WebServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation.

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/myServlet/*"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

No need for `web.xml` anymore. The above does basically the same as following:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myServlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As far now you can choose from under each [Glassfish v3](http://glassfish.java.net/) and [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org) as Servlet 3.0 implementations.

---

Prior to Servlet 3.0 your best bet is likely the front controller pattern. Have a single servlet in `web.xml` which delegates requests/actions to domain objects based on the request parameters and/or pathinfo. This is also used in the average MVC framework.

Comment: +1 - Nice.  How on earth do you keep up with all of this so well?  Most impressive.

Comment: My reading and playing aren't nearly as effective as yours.  Maybe I need to read less and play more.

Comment: @duffy: yes, playing helps definitely more than just reading. Own experience is the best knowledge source.

Comment: Great answer but the reason why I'm without a web.xml is because the company I work for hasn't upgraded our webserver since early 2000 and probably won't for a while. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397798/sun-one-web-server-configuration

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of help for you here. This is a server-specific problem and I have never used that server.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the class name to invoke the servlet in the webserver.
If your url is http://myurl.com/
Then, appending the full class name to the url will invoke the servlet.

Eg:
If my servlet is com.my.package.servlet.MyServlet
Then, you can use http://myurl.com/com.my.package.servlet.MyServlet
To pass parameters, http://myurl.com/com.my.package.servlet.MyServlet?name=myname&user=myuser

The url becomes dirty though. But you needn't use the web.xml to invoke the servlet.

Comment: Extremely bad advice. First, it works only on Tomcat and certain derived containers (the feature is exposed via the Invoker Servlet functionality). Second, there has been atleast one security bug in this area. More info at http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q3

Comment: @EJP: Yes, it's true.
@Vineet: It was not an advice to use it. Just an information that there is such a possibility to do without using web.xml.